# Angular 2 dynamic select options slow in Edge

Tags: performance, angular, selectlist, ngfor

I am using an *ngFor in Angular 2 Version: 4.0.1 to fill in 5 select lists on a page with the following code:

```
select [(ngModel)]="_materialInput.code" (change)="onChange()" formControlName="code" class="form-control" id="code">
    <option *ngFor="let x of _materialValues.code" value="{{x.key}}">{{x.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Each selection of an option causes the select list options to refresh from the server. This refresh is fast in other browsers.

I fount that the [UI Responsiveness Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvxQR.png) shows that when this update happens Edge removes these DOM elements one by one and updates the style then adds the new options back in one by one. This takes a long time.

I am using `import 'core-js/es6';` for my polyfills.

In my Winforms days I would use a BeginUpdate() EndUpdate() to keep this sort of thing from happening but I don't know of such a thing in the web world.

Does anyone know how to improve the performance in Edge?

Comment: Just a note, you don't actually have a question in your post :P

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no way to know specially why it is slow in Edge, but what is IE good for anyway!

The thing that you can do to speed up `*ngFor` is to use `trackBy` function inside `*ngFor`.

This example does something nice, which is, don't render again the whole list, rather if something changes, render that element again.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="_materialInput.code" (change)="onChange()" formControlName="code" class="form-control" id="code">
    <option *ngFor="let x of _materialValues.code; trackBy: trackByFn" value="{{x.key}}">{{x.value}}</option>
</select>
```

**Component**

```
  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; // or item.id
  }
```

See a detailed explanation from the great Netanel Basal:

https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5